Code in script tag of HTML within a flask app throwing small annoying errors
Home.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for("static",filename="css/css.css")}}">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to recipe book</h1>
<p>{{length}}</p>
<script>
const amount = "{{length}}";
let list = {{images | tojson}};
const base_URL = "{{ url_for('static',filename='images') }}"; 
const altText = {0:"Breakfast",1:"Lunch",2:"Dinner",3:"Snacks"};
for(let count=0;count<amount;count++){
    let current_image = document.createElement('img');
    let Cur_URL = base_URL + "/" + list[count];
    console.log(Cur_URL);
    current_image.setAttribute("src",Cur_URL);
    current_image.setAttribute('alt',altText[count]);
    current_image.setAttribute('height','200');
    current_image.setAttribute('width','auto');
    document.body.appendChild(current_image);
}   
</script>
</body>

</html>

main.py Flask python file:
#,redirect,url_for,send_from_directory,
from flask import Flask,render_template
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    parent  = r"C:\Users\khait\Desktop\Website\Recipe_Book\static\images"
    everything = os.listdir(parent)
    images = []
    for i in everything:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(parent,i)):
            images.append(os.path.join(i))
    length = len(images)
    return render_template("Home.html",images=images,length=length)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`

I was just trying to use the length variable in my html. and it throws these errors in relation to this line: "const amount = {{length}};" and this line "console.log(amount);":
Error 1:
Property assignment expected.javascript
Error 2:
Declaration or statement expected.javascript
I am aware many similar questions have been asked on this and I asked a similar one about the length variable. But that was a  numerical flask variable and this is a list flask variable. I looked through them and couldn't find an answer to my problem. I'm also interested to know what would the proper syntax be for boolean,char and string variables. I assume dict variables would have the same logic as the list variables. Right?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure it's related to the problem, but I don't think you should use os.path.join() when creating the elements of images. You're already prepending the directory path in JavaScript, you shouldn't have the full pathname as well.

When you look at the JavaScript in DevTools, is it replacing {{length}} properly?

Why do you need to use {{length}} in the first place? Can't you just use list.length? You can also loop over the array with list.forEach().

You have not set the value of the length variable; what is the length equals to?
Make sure you have passed the length variable on the function renders you HTML.

length = len(images)
return render_template("Home.html",images=images,length=length)
I have defined the value of length

i wanna use {{length}} so i can test whether i can implement both list type and number type variables into html  from flask bc i'm learning and wanna see how to do it. ik it may not be the most optimal way but i am just testing the possiblities

yes sorry that was acc an old typo. i did remove the parent diredctory from the inside of the if statement. I've updated the post now

somehow the code works but it stills throws these erros. and it doesn't like the "|" instead it wants "," which gives wrong results.

Can you post what View Source shows?

the first error is because when you use const amount = "{{length}}"; JavaScript interprets it as declaration but doesn't recognize the " as a valid JavaScript syntax.
The second error in referring to the fact that its expecting either a declaration or a statement since {{length}} isn't recognized as a valid JavaScript expression.
To correct it you need to remove the " from the {{length}} which directly assigns the value of length to amount and makes it valid for JS. and this works with every format, even JSON.

Try with const amount = Number("{{ length }}");
